# Audio compression and/or EQ for general podcast recording software

Tags: recording, compression, voice, podcasts, interview

I’m building general podcast recording software for users who are generally unfamiliar with audio. What is the best default configuration that I can provide for a dynamics compressor, filters, and/or EQ for users recording podcasts through this software?

Comment: There isn't one. Everything depends on input source, quality, timbre & intended output of each of those.

Comment: Is there anyway I could provide, say, 3–4 options for the most common cases? I expect this tool to be used by podcasters doing voice interviews only. Anything with needs above and beyond 2–5 people having a casual conversation probably aren't a good fit. So no NPR or nightvale level quality/timbre.

Comment: What are the parameters of your compressor? Filter cutoffs should always start fully open. Resonance value should start on zero(you don't have presets for filters alone, they would simply be user adjustable). EQ should be self-explanatory(zero(user-(saveable)) or presets) but we don't even know your EQ parameters; no. of bands etc.

Answer (score 1):

You really can't define specific parameters as "default". If you take a look at a compressor you'll notice the poti threshhold.
This basically specifies at which point the compressor will actually start working. Now not everyone's voice does output the same dB level. It's close to impossible to find a setting that works for everyone, just to name one of the issues.
You might want to approach a more versatile way. E.g. Build a couple of presets. One with a lower threshhold, another one with a higher. The low threshhold having almost a 1:1 ratio and more gain, while the higher threshhold has maybe 1:5 ratio and less gain, but still gains some presence through the compressor.
Additionally, keep in mind that some compressors work faster than others. If someone's tickling the threshhold every time he raises his voice and he does that frequently, because he feels the "rush of exitement", then he's gonna start pumping.
But I'm drifting off. If you wanna do it: don't try to find the "ultimate" setting. Do presets instead. 
Super interested to find out what your results are !! :)
Lemme know!!
Cheers!

Comment: Thresholds are almost always set to 0 dB by default, as this should be the starting point for most situations. Even in these presets you're talking about, the one feature that should be initially constant, but user-adjustable should be the threshold.